# What am I doing wrong in passing a struct around in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, reference

So I am working on a project in C that requires that I pass pointers to a struct into functions. The project is structured as follows:

```
struct structName {
    unsigned short thing2;
    char thing1[];
};

void function_1(struct structName *s) {
    strcpy(s->thing1, "Hello");
    printf("Function 1\n%s\n\n", s->thing1); // prints correctly
}

void function_2(struct structName *s) {
    // can read thing2's value correctly
    // thing1 comes out as a series of arbitrary characters
    // I'm guessing it's an address being cast to a string or something?

    printf("Function 2\n%s\n\n", s->thing1); // prints arbitrary characters ('É·/¨')
}

int main() {
    struct structName s;
    function_1(&s);
    printf("Main\n%s\n\n", s.thing1);
    function_2(&s);
    printf("Main 2\n%s\n\n", s.thing1);
}
```

This code outputs the following:

```
Function 1
Hello

Main
Hello

Function 2
É·/¨

Main 2
É·/¨
```

Obviously, the program has more than just what I've written here; this is just a simplified version; so if there's anything I should check that might be causing this let me know. In all honesty I reckon it's probably just a stupid rookie error I'm making somewhere.

[EDIT: Seems like `s.thing1` is being mutated in some way in the call to `function_2()`, since the odd value is replicated in `main()` - I should point out that in my program the `printf()`s are located right before the function call and in the first line of the function, so there's no chance that it's being written to by anything I'm doing. I've updated the example code above to show this.]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not valid C code. It doesn't compile.

Comment: `char thing1[];` is not valid. A flexible array member **must** be the last member of a `struct`.

Comment: Sorry, it is the last member in my code - will swap it now @user3386109

Comment: Unless it's imperative to have the string stored within the struct itself, it would be more common to just have a pointer as a member of your struct, and allocate memory separately for the string.  Flexible array members require a lot of care on the part of the programmer and may not be a good choice for someone getting started with the language.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for the advice; I'm currently using chqrlie's method but if I run into problems I'll give separate strings a try!

Comment: Did some further work and ended up being better off using a pointer to the string - thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure contains a flexible member at its end, if you declare a static object with this type, the length of this member will be zero, so `strcpy(s->thing1, "Hello");` will have undefined behavior.

You are supposed to allocate instances of this type of structure with enough extra space to handle whatever data you wish to store into the flexible array.

Here is an example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct pstring {
    size_t length;
    char data[];
} pstring;

pstring *allocate_pstring(const char *s) {
    size_t length = strlen(s);
    pstring *p = malloc(sizeof(*p) + length + 1);
    if (p != NULL) {
        p->length = length;
        strcpy(p->data, s);
    }
    return p;
}

void free_pstring(pstring *p) {
    free(p);
}

int main() {
    pstring *p = allocate_pstring("Hello");
    printf("Main\n%.*s\n\n", (int)p->length, p->data);
    free_pstring(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay - if I did need to have dynamic size for this, what would be the best alternative? This value is derived from user input and can be of any length.

Comment: @barnstorm3r: look at the example in the updated answer.

Comment: Will do; thank you! I'm new to C so was unconsciously a bit wary of using `malloc()` since it was somewhat foreign to me, but I'll give it a look now. Thanks again!

Comment: Just got it implemented; works perfectly, thanks a lot!